# Convert canvas composition to to svg filter

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, svg-filters

I'm trying to create a [svg filter](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html) to mimic the behaviour of this snippet:

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'color';
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
context.fill();

context.globalCompositeOperation = 'screen';
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)';
context.fill();
```

I used this filter:

```
<filter id="demoFilter">
    <feBlend mode="color" in="SourceGraphic" flood-color="white" flood-opacity="1" result="out1"/>
    <feBlend mode="screen" in="out1" flood-color="white" flood-opacity="0.5" result="out2"/>
</filter>
```

But the final effect is different as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2b9m5dqs/2/).

Any help?

Thanks in advice

Comment: What does "I'm not able to figure it out" mean? Because Stackoverflow is not a general help forum, so if you genuinely have no idea what to do, SO is probably the wrong place to ask. What have you (1) determined you might need to do based on the example, (2) in how many separate steps, with (3) what idea about the code you'll need to write and (4) how did that not work? (because if it did, you wouldn't be asking for help =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your hint, I added more context and the attempt made on Jsfiddle

Comment: Please remember to (re)read ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask): links to fiddles are fine, but only _in addition to_ showiing the ([mcve]) code in your post: questions should have all the information people need in order to help you. A few (small!) images and a description of what you think the filter does, which people can assume is your basis for the code you'll then show, wouldn't be a bad idea here, either.

Comment: Here is the feBlend documentation - which might be a good place to start since most of the attributes and attribute values you're using are not legal for feBlend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feBlend

Answer (score 0):

I've found a nice [SVG playground](https://yoksel.github.io/svg-filters/#/), very useful to understand how svg-filter works and to quick try new filters.

I was able to figure out a solution, using  `feFlood` to fill a region with the desidered color and alpha, and `feBlend` to define composition mode and stategy.

Here the working filter code:

```
<filter id="filter" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="flood"/>
    <feBlend mode="color" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend2"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="0.5" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="flood1"/>
    <feBlend mode="screen" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="blend2" in2="flood1" result="blend3"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: There is no mode="color" in SVG 1.1 - so this may not work on older browsers.

Comment: @MichaelMullany, thanks for point it out! Can I apply a matrix transformation to get the same result?

Comment: No, unfortunately this is a blending mode that can't be performed using other SVG 1.1 filter primitives